# How to insert form data into database using jquery in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.4

resources/views/index.blade.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            fname = $("#name").val();
            email = $("#email").val();
            phone = $("#phone").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"fname":fname, "email":email, "phone":phone,"_token":"{{csrf_token()}}"},
                url:"{{URL::to('save')}}",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#success").html(data);
                    $("#myform")[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="success"></div>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="myform">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter email">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('index');
    });
    Route::post('save','UserController@save');
```

api/Http/Controllers/UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller 
{
    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('fname');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $phone = $request->input('phone');
        $data=array('fname'=>$name,"email"=>$email,"phone"=>$phone);
        DB::table('emp')->insert($data);
        echo "<p style='color:green;padding:0px 10px;'>Record inserted successfully</p>";
    }
}
```

I am new in laravel 5 Now, I am trying to insert simple form value into the database through jQuery here what is the problem now when I click on submit button it shows nothing i.e. `no error` but when I am doing inspect element and check in `console` then it shows `http://localhost/freelara/save` not found I don't know why? Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank You

Comment: Can you please confirm if your url are working? If not check mod_rewrite module is enabled or not

Comment: actually, `index.blade.php` file is working but in case of form submit `http://localhost/freelara/save` not working.

Comment: Just create any url like /test and confirm if it is working

Comment: Or Route::any('save','UserController@save')

Comment: Then try to open  http://localhost/freelara/save directly on browser

Comment: I am trying `/test` and hit in url directly and it not also working @svikramjeet

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu ?

Comment: No, I am working on windows @svikramjeet

Comment: run with `php artisan serve` then after your url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/save`

Comment: Using WAMP click on wamp icon ->apache->apache modules->scroll and check rewrite_module Restart a LoadModule rewrite_module

Note, the server application restarts automatically for you once you enable "rewrite_module"

Comment: I am using `xampp` and I have already enabled `LoadModule rewrite_module` @svikramjeet

Comment: How you are accessing the home url?

Comment: Is http://localhost/freelara/public/test working ?

Comment: check my `routes/web.php` file

Comment: yes, `http://localhost/freelara/public/test` its working @svikramjeet

Comment: Thank you @svikramjeet I got the problem